# Tracking the position of the sun at various times of the day and night for a particular location

Tags: the-sun, solar-system, resource-request

I am looking for a website that will provide me with the degree above and below the horizon of the position of the sun at various times of the day and night for a particular location.
looking for suggestions.

Comment: Have you tried suncalc.org.  Questions asking for websites tend to dissolve into fairly unsortable lists.

Comment: Any planetarium software will do this.

Comment: [Horizons](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons/) can give you Apparent azimuth & elevation.

Comment: https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/api/horizons.api?format=text&COMMAND=10&CENTER=0%40399&QUANTITIES=4&ANG_FORMAT=DEG&APPARENT=REFRACTED&OBJ_DATA=NO&CAL_TYPE=G&START_TIME=%272024-Jan-1+6%3A00+UT%27&STOP_TIME=%272024-Jan-1+18%3A00%27&STEP_SIZE=1h

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where can I find the positions of the planets, stars, moons, artificial satellites, etc. and visualize them?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/13488/where-can-i-find-the-positions-of-the-planets-stars-moons-artificial-satellit)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determine sun azimuth and elevation for shading a window throughout the year](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/20092/determine-sun-azimuth-and-elevation-for-shading-a-window-throughout-the-year)

Comment: That's a good point - the community wiki answer to my proposed dupe lacks a good section for websites. Probably your suncalc.org plus things like https://www.gaisma.com/en/ (less useful in this case) need a section of their own in the wiki. I think that when this is closed both proposed dupes will show up, so I won't withdraw mine.

Comment: https://heavens-above.com/sun.aspx?lat=0&lng=0&loc=Unspecified&alt=0&tz=UCT (mind to set your location properly)